# A higher order function for sequential, conditional and modified function application?

Tags: python, functional-programming, monads

I'm writing Python in functional style (I think what I'm getting at is similar to a monad?). Here's what I have so far, hardcoded for three functions. What if I had 10 or 100?

```
    # a list of (function, function, function), each of which accept 
    # a scalar and return a list
    funcs = [(lambda a: [a, a], lambda a: [a, a, a], lambda a: [a])] * 10

    possible = []
    car = 3
    for a, b, c in funcs:
        ra = a(car)
        if ra:
            rb = b(ra[0])
            if rb:
                rc = c(rb[0])
                if rc: # last function
                    possible.extend(rc)
```

Comment: That is a bit strange.  Your lambdas return lists, but in the loop you ignore all but the first value of each list.  Can you explain in more detail what your goal is?

Comment: Descriptive variable names might assist everyone.

Comment: @BrenBarn Specifically I have three functions which I wish to apply in permutation, and if the whole chain works, then take the last result. I'm not interested in the intermediate values.

Answer (score 1):

That is very monadic.

What you'd probably want to do is run a fold using the monad's `bind` function (using the Maybe or Either monad in this case), though your individual functions would have to return a monadic value (i.e. the list value you want returned by the original function wrapped in the monad's particular value constructor).

Your end call would be something like this (in a mix of Haskell and Python):

```
fold Maybe.bind Maybe.mreturn(car) funcs
```

(You'd want the Maybe.bind to be in a lambda probably since python doesn't do partial application like Haskell, I was just being lazy.)

Here's a [python monad library/script](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/01/monads-in-python-with-nice-syntax.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
funcs = [(lambda a: [a, a], lambda a: [a, a, a], lambda a: [a])] * 10
initial = [3]
result = []
for function_chain on funcs:
    running = initial
    for function in function_chain:
        running = function(running[0])
        if not running[0]:
            break
    else:
        result.extend(running)
```